# upgradeble openzeppelin contracts - why the __gap is needed if you can add variables to the end?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, upgrading, contract-upgrading

[https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/upgradeable#storage_gaps](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/writing-upgradeable#modifying-your-contracts)

[1](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/writing-upgradeable#modifying-your-contracts): https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/upgradeable#storage_gaps explains why the `__gap` variable is needed, but https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/writing-upgradeable#modifying-your-contracts says "If you need to introduce a new variable, make sure you always do so at the end". So if I can just add a variable to the end, why is the `__gap` variable needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__gap` is used in base contracts to avoid storage clashes while using inheritance.

You cannot add new variables to base contracts if the child has any variables of its own. Given the following scenario:

`contract Base {  uint256 base1; }`

`contract Child is Base { uint256 child; }`

If Base is modified to add an extra variable:

`contract Base { uint256 base1; uint256 base2; }`

Then the variable base2 would be assigned the slot that child had in the previous version. A workaround for this is to declare unused variables on base contracts that you may want to extend in the future, as a means of "reserving" those slots. Note that this trick does not involve increased gas usage.

You can implement it like this:

`contract Base { uint256 base1; uint256[50] private __gap; }`

`contract Child is Base { uint256 child; }`

If Base is modified to add an extra variable:

`contract Base { uint256 base1; uint256 base2; uint256[49] private __gap; }`

Answer (score 0):

Check this out - https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-sdk/issues/912#issuecomment-496522759

In short, you should add variables before or after the __gap, and need to adjust the gap size in the mean time.

Comment: Not sure how it answers the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).